# Filtering if list elements are same in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, apply

I have a dataframe, which simply looks like this:

```
edges
      id       node_id     ...
0   'AX'    ['A', 'B']
1   'BX'    ['B', 'C']
2   'CX'    ['C', 'C']
```

The `'id'` column has string elements, and the `'node_id'` column has lists (with strings inside).

I would like to remove some elements from this pandas `df`, if their 'node_id' has 2 same string.

In above dataframe this would be the 2nd element since its `'node_id'` has `'C'` and `'C'`.

To do that, I am using the following:

```
edges[edges['node_id'].apply(lambda x: x[0]) != edges['node_id'].apply(lambda x: x[1])]
```

However, since `.apply()` is not really time efficient, I am looking for a built-in pandas function. Is there any to achieve what I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['AX', 'BX', 'CX'],
    'node_id': [['A','B'],['B', 'C'],['C', 'C']]})

mask = df['node_id'].apply(lambda x : x[0]!=x[1])

df = df[mask]
```

Output:

```
    id  node_id
0   AX  [A, B]
1   BX  [B, C]
```

If you have multi item in `list` you can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['AX', 'BX', 'CX'],
    'node_id': [['A', 'B', 'C'],['B', 'C', 'C'],['C', 'C', 'C']]})

mask = df['node_id'].apply(lambda x : len(x)==len(set(x)))

df = df[mask]
```

Output:

```
id  node_id
0   AX  [A, B, C]
```

Comment: isn't this the same thing, that I do? or it is running apply only ones therefore it is better?

Comment: @oakca you want to check `list` in `node_id` don't same each other, you need one time see all `list` in `node_id`, this code run one time and order is O(n) and best solution for you definitely have O(n) order

Comment: yeah, since I was running apply function twice mine was worse than this! ty

Comment: @oakca exactly, and if you have multi item you can use `set()`

Answer (score 1):

Another version using only **vectorized functions** and **without using `.apply()`**:

Filter to keep only rows with *"length of unique items in the list"* is equal to *"length of the list"*:

Set mask for the condition *"length of unique items in the list"* == *"length of the list"*, and then filter by the mask:

[`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) each list in `node_id` with [`pd.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) to get the unique item list:

```
mask = df['node_id'].map(pd.unique).str.len() == df['node_id'].str.len()
df.loc[mask]
```

**Data Input:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':      ['AX',       'BX',         'CX'],
    'node_id': [['A','B'],  ['B', 'C'],   ['C', 'C']]})


   id node_id
0  AX  [A, B]
1  BX  [B, C]
2  CX  [C, C]
```

**Result**

```
   id node_id
0  AX  [A, B]
1  BX  [B, C]
```

**Result:**

Comment: if you put a benchmark between this and `.apply()`. I will accept your answer, since I -in the first place- was looking for a solution without `.apply()`. But for documentation reasons, it would be also good, if you would share a benchmark.